# MySQL & SqLite - compatibile timestamp compare

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

I have php app with test using SqLite, but on production I have MySQL.

Some of my code use date compare in where clause, but SqLite don't support NOW() function.

In MySQL I have:

```
Select * from `table` where arrive_date < NOW();
```

where arrive_date is timestamp type.

In SqLite I should use some substitute for NOW(), but I don't want other part of codes for tests and production.

Maybe it's a way to write that SQL to make it work on both engine?

Comment: Why not run a test MySQL server?

Comment: Because of performance. In memory SqLite is faster than MySQL.

Comment: So not only can you not use MySQL specific syntax and functions, now you have no feel for actual performance during development. If the MySQL performance is slowing you down in development, chances are it is making for a sluggish application in general.

Comment: No, MySQL perfrormance it's not a general problem. I have a lot of tests, and every time DB is truncated and rebuilded, in MySQL it's taking more time. That's why I want memory DB for tests.

Comment: Ah, that makes a little more sense; but it still seems like tying one hand behind your back, and opening yourself to less obvious errors that will only appear in production. (But I will bow out now, as it isn't really relevant to the actual question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `SQLite` you can use `DATETIME()` function like

```
select * from `table` 
where arrive_date < datetime('now');
```

You can use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for both cases like

```
select * from `table` 
where arrive_date < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: Yeah, sure, but It's not what I want.
I need one universal SQL for both engine.

Comment: @Son, `NOW()` doesn't exists for SQLite; not sure if I have misunderstood your question but you can't use now() if you are testing in SQLite.

Comment: You right, and that is a clue of my question. I want to know whether there is a way to write SQL what will do the same, and will be work on both engine replacing NOW() something else.

Comment: @Son, yeah you can use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for both DB types.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul, thats work perfectly. How could I forget about CURRENT_TIMESTAMP @_@.